# The story of Prithu chasing Prithvi

Tags: scripture, vishnu, krishna, rama, story

I have read an Wikipedia article on Prithu (an incarnation of Vishnu) and the story of him chasing Prithvi who later agreed to give vegetation and grains? What is the story of this incarnation of Vishnu and which scripture explains this story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The story of Prithu chasing Prithvi comes in the Bhagavata Purana's 4th Skandha (book.)

But first, you need to know who Prithu was.

Prithu was obviously the Amsha of Vishnu:

> 3. This (Pṛthu) is a manifestation of that aṃśa (portion) of Lord Viṣṇu which protects the world. This sister of Prthu (Pṛthu?) is the portion and incarnation of Goddess Lakṣmī who is never disunited from the Supreme Man (Viṣṇu). (Srimad Bhagavatam, Book IV, Chapter 15)

However, Prithu was the son of Vena, an unrighteous King who disregarded the righteousness of Brahmins and made them worship him:

> 28. Therefore, Oh Brāhmaṇas! Being free from jealousy, you worship me with your religious rites. Give me all your offerings (taxes etc.). What other person than me, deserves to be propitiated (honoured) for it? (Srimad Bhagavatam, Book IV, Chapter 14)

When Prithu became the king of Earth, his people became very sick and hungry.

> 9. Dear child (Vidura)! When Pṛthu was coronated and was called as the protector of the public, the subjects with their bodies emaciated with hunger due to barrenness of the earth, approached Pṛthu, the protector and appealed.
> 10. “Oh King! We are oppressed by the gastric fire just like the wood with fire in its hollow. Today we have approached you for shelter, as you are installed as our king who will provide us with means of livelihood, and are worthy of seeking asylum.
> 11. Oh King of kings! You are verily the protector of the people and the bestower of the means of livelihood. Therefore, while we have not perished from starvation, Your Majesty should endeavour to supply food to us who are famished with hunger.” (Srimad Bhagavatam, Book IV, Chapter 17)

Prithu concluded that Bhudevi (Prithvi) must be hiding food and resources from Prithu. He became so enraged he wanted to kill her.

> 13. By his reasoning power he came to the conclusion (that the earth had held up the seeds of herbs, plants and food-grains within herself). Being indignant, he took up his bow and fitted an arrow on it aiming at the earth, just as the enraged destroyer of Tripura (Śiva, did against Tripura).
> 14. When the earth saw the king with his weapon uplifted, she began to tremble. She assumed the form of a cow and in terror began to run fast like a terrified female deer chased by a hunter.
> 15. The enraged son of Vena, with eyes blood-red with wrath, and with the arrow fitted to his bow, chased after her whithersoever she ran (for shelter).
> 16. Running to all the directions (cardinal points) and intermediate directions (e.g. South-east, South-west etc.), to the heaven and the earth and in the space between them, the goddess Earth saw him chasing her everywhere with uplifted weapon.
> 17. Just as people do not get protection from death, she did not get any asylum in the world against Pṛthu, the son of Vena. Terrified, she returned with a troubled heart.

Prithvi eventually agrees to give him his resources in the form of milk.

> 9-10. Oh mighty-armed hero! Oh protector of creatures! If Your Lordship desires (to provide) nutritious food coveted by creatures, please arrange for a calf, a suitable vessel (milk-pot) and a milk-man competent to draw (my) milk, so that, being full of affection, I shall yield for you all your desired objects in the form of milk, Oh warrior.
>
> 11. Oh mighty king! Make me a level plain so that the waters showered by god Indra may stand on me, even after the rainy season is over. God may bless you.”
> 12. Accepting the agreeable and wholesome words of advice of the goddess of the earth, the king made (Svāyam- bhuva) Manu as the calf, and milked all the herbs and plants (such as cereals etc.), in his own hand.
> 13. Similarly, other wise men also extracted essence of everything everywhere. Then others (fifteen including sages) drew out their desired objects from the cow (earth) tamed by Pṛthu.

---

Hope this helped!

Comment: you have mentioned "Prithu was born as an unrighteous king? and also when Vishnu assumed the form of king? Why would the people suffer?

Comment: Correction, Prithu wasn't the unrighteous one. According to the sources, when Vena died, the sage at first churned his body, from which first emerged Nishada (the unrighteous one) & on the 2nd time emerged Prithu. Vena had angered everyone in his kingdom by disregarding the Vaidika faith (purpotedly under the influence of Jainism), so the Vaidika deities punished his subjects for their king's blasphemous acts.

Comment: @Shashaank I'm afraid I don't understand your question? It was stated that the subjects of Prithu were sick and hungry as Prithvi Devi wanted to hold her resources within herself. Are you asking why this would happen if Prithu was Vishnu's avatar? Well, it's stated Prithu was an Amsh-Avatar of Vishnu. Just like Parshurama (an Amsh-Avatar of Vishnu) fought Rama (an actual Avatar of Vishnu), an Amsh-Avatar is gifted with the intelligence and strength of Vishnu but is not Vishnu Himself. Perhaps Prithvi Devi was punishing Prithu, it is not stated so I can only make conclusions. My apologies.

Comment: @AnubrataBit Are you sure that was apart of the Srimad Bhagavatam chapter? If so, I must have skipped it. My apologies.

Comment: @Shashaank I have made a crucial mistake by saying Prithu was unrighteous. He wasn't, instead Vedavyasa was describing Nishada, his brother. I'm sorry, and I've fixed it immediately.

Comment: So people suffered because of Nishada and not because of Prithu? @HariharaVishnumShivah

Comment: @Shashaank It seems like Vena's bad ruling bad ruling caused people to suffer, not Prithu. Nishada never ruled as he immediately became an ascetic forest dweller (Nishada, literally) to alleviate his sins and his father's. Prithu was coronated after Vena had died, but before this, there was a small period where Vena died and Prithu ruled, that there was no ruler and the subjects of Earth succumbed to illness and hunger. So people suffered due to Vena's rule and death.

Comment: Prithu had nothing to do with the suffering of his subjects.

Comment: But why was Prithvi scared of Prithu?, Isn't she Vishnu's wife?

Comment: @Shashaank I am ashamed to say that I have some things wrong in my answer. I have fixed it though. I looked at the Sanskrit text for this chapter, and was making sure the translation was correct, but I saw that "this Prithvi" is not the correct translation. When it was talking about a female being the incarnation of Devi Lakshmi, it was referring to Prithu's sister. From King Vena was also a daughter, who was the sister of Prithu. This is why it says that she can never be separated from Him. It was referring to his sister but not Prithvi Devi herself.

Comment: Oh, So the prithivi is his sister Not Lakshmi herself?

Comment: @Shashaank Ganganath Jha made a small commentary on this: "अधर्मी राजा वेण की संप्रभु बेटी अर्चि, हालांकि पृथु की बहन के बाद से वह वेना से भी पैदा हुई थी, शादी कर ली। इस समय बहनों का अपने भाइयों से विवाह करना अक्सर होता था। यही कारण है कि श्रीमद्भागवत पुराण में कहा गया है कि वे कभी अलग नहीं होंगे क्योंकि वे भाई-बहन थे, बल्कि पत्नी और पति भी थे। अर्ची देवी लक्ष्मी का एकमात्र अवतार थीं।" This means that Devi Lakshmi had incarnated as Devi Archi, the daughter of King Vena, but also as the wife of Prithu, as it was common for siblings to be married at this time.

Comment: This is why the Srimad Bhagavatam Purana says they could never be separated.

Comment: Devi Prithvi is not the incarnation of Devi Lakshmi.

Comment: Devi Archi was not Devi Prithvi? and is Devi Prithvi the second wife of Vishnu? You have mentioned that Devi Prithvi was an incarnation of Lakshmi?

Comment: @Shashaank If I ever said Devi Prithvi was an incarnation of Devi Lakshmi, I must have accidentally said that or misexplained, because it isn't true. Devi Archi is not Devi Prithvi. Devi Prithvi is not Devi Lakshmi. If Devi Prithvi was a wife of Prithu, and an incarnation of Devi Lakshmi, she would never have been scared of Prithu. Rather, she ran around Earth scared for her life.

Comment: Devi Archi is the first and only wife of Prithu. Her story of being his wife isn't relevant much, because most of the chapter in the Srimad Bhagavatam was the explanation of Prithu's actions to get resources from Devi Prithvi.

Comment: I'm sorry if I made any confusion. If you have any more questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: So was Prithvi the second wife of Vishnu? And is this the same Prithvi saved by Varaha Avatar?

Comment: Prithvi was not the wife of Vishnu or Prithu. In the Rigveda, Prithvi is the wife of the sky god called Dyaus/Prabhasa/Akasha Deva. This deva is the incarnation of the later Bhishma in the Mahabharata from a curse. Not much is known about Dyaus Deva, but Prithvi was his only wife.

Comment: But, in the Puranas, it is said Prithvi has a second husband who is Vishnu's avatar called Varaha. After Varaha saved Prithvi, they got married and begot a son called Narakasura who was slain by Shri Krishna. But I am not sure if this is the same Prithvi since it contradicts Rigveda.

Comment: But the Prithvi in this story is the same one saved by Shri Varaha, yes.